# MDB access using php

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc, jet

I am having a little bit of trouble trying to write to a .mdb database from php.

The database has a table called comments and it has 3 columns "id", "comment" and "by".  The code I have is this.

```
<?php

$count =0;
$db_path = "newsBlog.mdb";
$odbc_con = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$constr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" . $db_path . ";";
$odbc_con -> open($constr);

$sql = "INSERT INTO [comments] VALUES (".$_POST['newsId'].",'".$_POST['comment']."', '".$_POST['by']."')";
echo $sql;
$odbc_con -> execute (sql);

$rs = null;
$conn = null;

echo "done";
?>
```

It takes 3 values from a form on the previous page and should insert them into the database, except I get this error every time:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '&lt;b&gt;Source:&lt;/b&gt; Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers&lt;br/&gt;&lt;b&gt;Description:&lt;/b&gt; [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.' in D:\Hosting\7010757\html\users\kinectfashion\postComment.php:20 Stack trace:
#0 D:\Hosting\7010757\html\users\kinectfashion\postComment.php(20): com-&gt;execute('sql')
#1 {main}   thrown in <b>D:\Hosting\7010757\html\users\kinectfashion\postComment.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

To me, this seams MAD as I am using an insert statement and cannot see what I am doing wrong!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$odbc_con -> execute (sql);` should be `$odbc_con -> execute ($sql);`

Comment: oh dear oh dear oh dear.  Thank you so much, I shall now hang my head in shame for such a basic, dumb error!

Thank you so much, i doubt i would have ever spotted that tbh!

Comment: If you enable `E_NOTICE` level error reporting, you'll get warned about such errors. PHP will complain about `Use of undefined constant sql - assumed 'sql'`

Comment: `a basic, dumb error` ... that would be using the JET driver in 2011.

Comment: @todda.speot.is : do you know of any alternative?

Comment: @Mchl I second that! What is a better, more modern way of doing that @todda.speot.is?  Most of my knowledge is cobbled together from old tutorials/whatever I can find online and I agree that most of it is probably out dated. Any pointers would be most welcome!  Thanks

Comment: Typically your web host will give you a database like MySQL or SQL Server to use. They are much more powerful and reliable than JET.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: You are right. Using JET for web application is not wise, and using it in a project starting in 2011 is doubly so. However, there are still people like me or Ewen, who need to support legacy systems, that just won't die. Even though my PHP-MySQL-MongoDB application does all the heavy work in the company, I still need to insert some data into MS Access reporting app (good thing I don't need to retrieve any). I would love to drop it, but I can't.

Comment: First, `Access != JET`. Second, look at linked tables in Access. You can link to tables in (effectively) any ODBC data source in Access and insert/delete/update the data. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html

Comment: I know that. Unfortunately in my case there simply is no budget to migrate this app. I know that in ideal world you could always move to better technology. We don't live in ideal world unfortunately. We use MS Access 2002. No money for upgrades, and this version can only work with JET AFAIK.

Comment: The fatal error mentioned is on `$odbc_con -> open($constr);`  !!
This is what I also get when I apply the exact code given.